# How I return equipaments not active in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return all serials from equipaments table which is not active in contract table

```
table equipaments
    id, serial
     1  111
     2  222
     3  333

table contract_equipament
    id, id_contrato, serial, status
     1     5       ,  111  , active
     2     6       ,  111  , inactive
     3     7       ,  222  , inactive
```

I want that result looks like:

```
serial
 222
 333
```

I try to use a left join, but I can't get a satisfying answer for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like `not exists`:

```
select e.*
from equipments e
where not exists (select 1
                  from contracts c
                  where c.serial = e.serial and
                        c.status = 'active'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM equipaments e 
INNER JOIN contract_equipament ce 
ON e.id = ce.id
WHERE ce.STATUS = 'inactive'
```

Comment: Please add appropriate description to your answer